# cannot convert nan to int (but there are no nans)

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with a column of floats that I want to convert to int:

```
> df['VEHICLE_ID'].head()
0    8659366.0
1    8659368.0
2    8652175.0
3    8652174.0
4    8651488.0
```

In theory I should just be able to use:

```
> df['VEHICLE_ID'] = df['VEHICLE_ID'].astype(int)
```

But I get:

```
Output: ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer
```

But I am pretty sure that there are no NaNs in this series:

```
> df['VEHICLE_ID'].fillna(999,inplace=True)
> df[df['VEHICLE_ID'] == 999]
> Output: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [VEHICLE_ID]
Index: []
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Basically the error is telling you that you `NaN` values and I will show why your attempts didn't reveal this:

```
In [7]:
# setup some data
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1.0, np.NaN, 3.0, 4.0]})
df
Out[7]:
     a
0  1.0
1  NaN
2  3.0
3  4.0
```

now try to cast:

```
df['a'].astype(int)
```

this raises:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer
```

but then you tried something like this:

```
In [5]:
for index, row in df['a'].iteritems():
    if row == np.NaN:
        print('index:', index, 'isnull')
```

this printed nothing, but `NaN` cannot be evaluated like this using equality, in fact it has a special property that it will return `False` when comparing against itself:

```
In [6]:
for index, row in df['a'].iteritems():
    if row != row:
        print('index:', index, 'isnull')

index: 1 isnull
```

now it prints the row, you should use `isnull` for readability:

```
In [9]:
for index, row in df['a'].iteritems():
    if pd.isnull(row):
        print('index:', index, 'isnull')

index: 1 isnull
```

So what to do? We can drop the rows: `df.dropna(subset='a')`, or we can replace using `fillna`:

```
In [8]:
df['a'].fillna(0).astype(int)

Out[8]:
0    1
1    0
2    3
3    4
Name: a, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 11):

**When your series contains floats and nan's and you want to convert to integers**, you will get an error when you do try to convert your float to a numpy integer, because there are na values.

**DON'T DO:**

```
df['VEHICLE_ID'] = df['VEHICLE_ID'].astype(int)
```

**From pandas >= 0.24 there is now a built-in pandas integer. This does allow integer nan's. Notice the capital in `'Int64'`.** This is the pandas integer, instead of the numpy integer.

**SO, DO THIS:**

```
df['VEHICLE_ID'] = df['VEHICLE_ID'].astype('Int64')
```

More info on pandas integer na values:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/gotchas.html#nan-integer-na-values-and-na-type-promotions

Comment: This should be the correct answer from now on IMO, since this solution gives back the DataFrame `NaN` 's untouched while converting actual float numbers to integers. But be careful to capital letter `I` in `Int64`. If you try `int64` instead of `Int64` it still gives the same error.