# Change values in one column based on condition of another column's values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For the following screenshot, I want to change the `NaN` values under the `total_claim_count_ge65` to a `5` if the values of the `ge65_suppress_flag` have the `#` symbol.

[image: screenshot]

I want to use a for loop to go through the `ge65_suppress_flag` column and every time it encounters a `#` symbol, it will change the `NaN` value in the very next column (`total_claim_count_ge65`) to a `5`.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985063/cannot-convert-nan-to-int-but-there-are-no-nans did it help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```py
df[df['ge65_suppress_flag'] == '#']['total_claim_count_ge65'].fillna(5, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a similar data frame

```
import pandas
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"ge65_suppress_flag": ['bla', 'bla', '#', 'bla'], "total_claim_count_ge65": [1.0, 2.0, None, 4.0]})
```

Filling in 5.0 in rows where `ge65_suppress_flag` column value equals to '#'

```
df1.loc[df1['ge65_suppress_flag']=="#", 'total_claim_count_ge65'] = 5.0
```

Comment: Thanks Permanent Pon. This worked pretty well. What I had for the screen shot was a fraction of the data I am looking at and I used your idea with a small modification. I turned the 2 columns into lists and I used them in the data frame method to do the entirety of the columns which consist of about  1 millions rows. I wonder if there is a way to do this without having to create a new data frame.

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain step-by-step after giving you a solution.

Here's a one-liner that will work.

```py
df[df[0]=='#'] = df[df[0]=='#'].fillna(5)
```

To make the solution more general, I used the column's index based on your screenshot. You can change the index number, or specify by name like so:

```py
df['name_of_column']
```

Step-by-step explanation:

First, you want to use the variable attributes in your first column `df[0]` to select only those equal to string `'#'`:

```py
df[df[0]=='#']
```

Next, use the pandas [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method to replace all variable attributes that are `np.NaN` with `5`:

```py
df[df[0]=='#'].fillna(5)
```

According to the `fillna` documentation, this function returns a new dataframe. So, to avoid this, you want to set the subsection of your dataframe to what is returned by the function:

```py
df[df[0]=='#'] = df[df[0]=='#'].fillna(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `df.apply` with a `lambda`:

```
d = {'ge65_suppress_flag': ['not_supressed','not_supressed','#'], 'total_claim_count_ge65': [516.03, 881.0, np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['total_claim_count_ge65'] = df.apply(lambda x: 5 if x['ge65_suppress_flag']=='#' else x['total_claim_count_ge65'], axis=1)
print(df)
```

prints:

```
  ge65_suppress_flag  total_claim_count_ge65
0      not_supressed                  516.03
1      not_supressed                  881.00
2                  #                    5.00
```

Comment: Thank-you pink spikyhairman. This worked really well. The screenshot came from a data set that has about 1 million columns.  I  turned the columns into lists and applied your code which was able to do all of the rows. I wonder if there is a way to do this without having to create a new data frame. Say these two columns were 2 of 70 columns in a big data frame You would have to create this new data frame and then go back into the main bigger data frame and merge these 2 new columns and delete the 2 old columns.

Comment: if you have the original 70 columns of data in a dataframe ```df```, with the column names the same, then the line ```df['total_claim_count_ge65'] = df.apply(lambda x: 5 if x['ge65_suppress_flag']=='#' else x['total_claim_count_ge65'], axis=1)``` of my solution will work on that dataframe as-is.